# How to Root LG Optimus Slider VM701?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, rooting, lg-optimus-slider

I tried Gingerbreak.apk also connecting via usb to my laptop, downloaded LG drivers, then LG Esteem Root file, but upon running the excute/Run file it says "Press Enter to begin Root"; then it says "Waiting on Device" but nothing happens after that. I turned on "USB Debugging" & "Allow Downloads from Unknown Sources" but neither method worked? Specifications: Android 2.3.4; Baseband: VM701ZV4_6170; Kernel 2.6.35.7+ lgandroid- build#2; Build# GRJ22 ; SW Version- VM701ZV4